# devise_scope no object error, Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I´ve installed `gem 'devise'` into a basic Ruby On Rails app and when trying to change my "/users/sign_in" route to "/users" by typing in the following into my routes.rb file;

```
devise_scope :user do
  get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

I get the following error, when trying to initiate the server;

> /Users/tony/projects/collabfield/config/routes.rb:6:in `<main>':
>   undefined method`devise_scope' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

I have no idea what´s wrong.

Comment: you can't change login route to `/users` because its already defined . as you write this route in route file, try to visit `/users/login`, it will work. let me know if you get any error

Comment: `undefined method devise_scope` I also have no idea what's wrong. According to the official documentation, if you have installed `devise` properly then that should work. Can you provide a [mcve]? Did you run `bundle install`? How are you running the server? (For example, could the gem not be loaded due to some cacheing?) Can you reproduce it on a brand new app?

Comment: @Vishal apologies, what I meant is I am trying to change "the users/sign_in" route to "/login". The issue is "devise_scope" is not recognized. Thanks :)

Comment: @TomLord I included gem 'devise' in my Gemfile. Saved it and then ran "bundle install" in the terminal. The gem seemed to be well installed, because I could successfully  "rails generate devise User" and "rails generate devise:views"- both the routes and the views were successfully generated. My server is Puma and my current Rails version is 5.2.0. I´m going to try in a new app. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that within config/routes.rb, the code must be as follows;

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_scope :user do
        get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    end 
end
```

I was previously only inserting the following;

```
devise_scope :user do
    get 'login', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

Comment: Ohhh... Yeah, this is why I asked for a [mcve]. I wouldn't have guessed that "typing in the following into my routes.rb" (on line 6) would be outside of the `Rails.application.routes.draw` block!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I needed to restart the rails server. This was because I had just installed the new `devise` gem.